# How to not execute a stubbed method in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing that a controller calls a certain method in a module that it includes. I don't want the method to actually execute, just to verify that it is called. What I have right now is:

```
it 'calls create_show_and_tickets' do
  sign_in create :admin
  expect(subject).to receive(:create_show_and_tickets)

  post :create, show: valid_attributes
end
```

In the test I am not putting proper parameters in, so it is throwing an error when I tries to iterate over an object that doesn't exist. Is there a way to make sure that `create_show_and_tickets` does not execute?

Comment: The code looks correct. If it's not working as expected, could you show how your are setting `subject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make sure that create_show_and_tickets does not execute?

You have done just that by calling

```
expect(subject).to receive(:create_show_and_tickets)
```

... before the post. `allow` would have the same effect. In either case the underlying code is replaced by your mock or stub, and will not get called.

You can put a debugging statement within `create_show_and_tickets` to confirm this.